Line Gutter in Oracle Sql Developer is not aligned with SQL Code Editor
I am using Oracle Sql Developer latest version (at the moment of writing this) 22.2.1.234 build 234.1810.
I have the Code Editor Pane configured for Font Size=17, and I show line numbers using the line gutter.
Tools > Preferences > Code Editor > Fonts;  Select Font Size=17
Tools > Preferences > Code Editor > Line Gutter; check "Show Line Numbers"
I notice that when I open sqldeveloper, the line gutter is not aligned correctly with the actual lines in the code editor.
I found a kind of "workaround" for this.  I change the Font Size from 17 to 18 and then the gutter alignes itself, then i change it back to 17 and the guter realigns.  But i have to repeat this every time i close and reopen sqldeveloper.
Q1: Am I the only one having this issue?
Q2: Any advice on a permanent solution?
Thanks Everyone.
Marcelo

How far off is it? You should know we also have a SQL Developer extension for vs code if you're looking for the best editor experience.
